# Should you pick the starting size of a CNN filters/kernels depending on the actual size of the objects you intend to detect/analyse?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I was reading about some famous CNN architectures such as AlexNet and I was wondering if the size of kernels was usually related to the size of faces, birds, cars, etc.. on a typical image?

When designing a new CNN is there a general rule of thumb for picking the "first guess" size of a kernel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the early days of CNNs, feature/kernel sizes were as large as 11x11 or 13x13.  These large kernels create a large number of trainable parameters per kernel - 121 and 169, resp. - which contributes to a problem of vanishing or exploding gradients However, it has been found that smaller kernels - typically 5x5 or 3x3 - provide similar performance while lowering the gradient problem.  (I cannot find the specific paper that investigated this, but if I find it I'll link it here.)

Also, while a larger kernel can identify more complex features, keeping kernels smaller allows them to find more basic features that may be pertinent to different types of images.  These simpler features are usually edges or gradients which can then be combined into more complex features in later layers of the network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Is the size of 5x5 an absolute value regardless of the size of the picture?

Is a 4K screenshot and a 1000x1000 image supposed to use those same values ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, but I don't have direct experience with images that size.  You could just as easily go to 7x7, 9x9 or higher, but I think anything higher will just increase the number of trainable parameters and may not provide any benefit and potentially issues with gradients.  A smaller kernel will still be able to detect edges and gradients, and then deeper layers of the network can combine them into more complex features related to your images.